# Does lock.wait(1) *guarantee* that threads competing over the lock will grab it in this time?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have a controller thread that is **permanently** in `synchronized(lock)`: It does a calculation step, then it does `wait(1000)`, then it checks if more work is to be done. If so, it does another step and waits(1000). If not, it just waits(1000) straightaway. (Mind that I'm using **wait**, not **sleep**.)

Sometimes, the calculation steps called by the controller ask the controller to call them many times in a row - that's a high performance mode lasting for multiple seconds. During this time, no other thread (e.g. Swing) could alter data used by this controller thread. Swing would now hang if it tried to do this!

I want to keep the balance between high performance and good fluidity.

Therefore, I want to add `wait(1)` in this high performance mode loop.

**QUESTION: Will a thread waiting to grab the `lock` achieve dominance with ABSOLUTE certainty, if I sprinkle these `wait(1)` calls into the calculation loop?**

Comment: try it but pretty certain that's a no and your code sounds like you should reevaluate what you do because waiting is almost certainly a bad idea. There are blocking queues for waiting on work

Comment: I second @zapl. Why the one second wait? Why not have the "calculation" thread pick tasks from a blocking queue, and perform them as soon as/whenever they are requested? Your "high performance mode" in that case would simply be the client loading up the queue with a sequence of tasks all at once.

Comment: I'm not sure I could do it like that. My application supplies graphical blocks that perform tasks (download file from FTP, read one record from file, iterate over all records of file, ...) that the user can graphically connect. This editor competes over the data structure with the controller thread that executes all this.

Answer (score -1):

> QUESTION: Will a thread waiting to grab the lock achieve dominance with ABSOLUTE certainty, if I sprinkle these wait(1) calls into the calculation loop?

The short answer is sort of in that you are always getting the lock when `lock.wait(1)` returns.  However, I don't think you understand how to use lock and notify to gain control over a shared resource. To call `lock.wait(1)` you need to own the lock to start with.
The call releases the lock and returns either if `lock.notify()` or `notifyAll()` was called or if the timeout expires **and** (NOTE) the lock is available to be locked again.  This means that if someone else owns the lock for a long period of time, the `wait(...)` method won't return unless the lock is released – which could be for many milliseconds.  It is designed to help threads coordinate between themselves.

If the question is "does calling `wait(1)` in a calculation loop only give the lock to other people for 1ms" then the answer is no.

If you have a resource that can only be used by one thread at a time then the other threads will need to wait until it is available.  You hope that each thread uses the resource for a short amount of time so the waiting is small.

You can protect the resource using a couple of different mechanisms.  The easiest is to just put a `synchronized` block around its use.  This protects it from race conditions and ensures that any changes to the resource gets published to main memory in all threads.  No wait or notify calls are required using this mechanism.

Another way of doing it is to use `lock.wait(...)` and `lock.notify()`.  This mechanism is required when (for example) threads are consuming from a collection and need to wait for there to be entities added.  In this case, when a thread adds an entity to the collection it calls `lock.notify()` and any thread(s) waiting for work in `lock.wait()` will be notified that there is work to do and will awaken.

The use of the `lock.wait(...)` timeout argument means that threads can wait for a certain amount of time for the resource to be available before giving up.  In the queue processing example above, the threads may need to check if the application is shutting down every second or so.  So they call `lock.wait(1000)`, test if the shutdown flag has been set, and if not they can check for work to be done and then call wait again.  Just because you are calling `lock.wait(1)` doesn't ensure any sort of lock "dominance" and doesn't mean that the method returns after 1ms.

If you want to use wait and notify signaling then you would need a secondary variable to check to see if the resource is in use.  The following example uses an `inUse` boolean field.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
private boolean inUse = false;
...

synchronized (lock) {
   while (inUse) {
       lock.wait();
   }
   inUse = true;
}
// use the resource
...
synchronized (lock) {
   inUse = false;
   lock.notify();
}
```

Notice that the example tests for `inUse` in a `while` loop and not just an `if`.  This is an important pattern and is needed because you could be notified but another thread might have gotten access to the resource while you were waiting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I think it's buggy: We probably have to just remove the "!" inversion to fix it. ---- If I understand correctly, you mean to set a boolean from the desiring thread, so that the busy thread can relinquish control until the boolean is cleared. This would require the boolean to be `volatile` instead of protected by the lock, since the lock can't be acquired (that's the key problem after all). I like the idea - I could just change my current unconditional `wait(1)` call to `while(dontBeSoBusy){wait(1)}` which would **guarantee** that Swing will get in&out quickly ...

Comment: ... to change some data, and then the calculation can continue burning the processor. ---- I will not do it like this because it would require me to think of **setting&clearing** that boolean for every situation where Swing directly or indirectly tries to obtain the lock, so if I forget that in a place, the problem of Swing freezing for a couple of seconds might only be revealed once the software is deployed on customer PCs, and they wouldn't know if this is intentional or to report it, would probably just suffer it without active reflection. ...

Comment: ... Since the project is very complex, I must assume I will make mistakes, so I must design it so the amount of critical code is minimal, which prohibits this design. ---- It would be ideal if all Java implementations' threading worked like this: If threads are queued up for lock control, threads that got there from wait()-timeout always have lowest priority, so that threads that had been waiting for control would be guaranteed to get it even in a wait(1) scenario. My question is aimed to produce an answer based on JVM design knowledge (or to produce an alternative solution that I can accept).

Comment: You will need to use a lock if there is contention with other threads.  That's how it works.  You can't just use a `volatile` boolean unless you spin which is typically wasteful.  You don't need a `volatile` _and_ a lock so pick one.  I'm afraid that without more details about the contention between the threads, I can't help with any solution.

Comment: If that's your response then I must have interpreted your answer wrong. - So how does your answer relate to my question of the busy calculation thread that wants to let a desiring thread in? I can't just call wait() every time, that would just HALT the busy thread. It would have to be a wait() with a timeout.

Comment: If you have a resource under contention that can only be used by one thread then you have to call `wait()`.  What you hope is that the other thread will use the resource and immediately call `notify()` so the wait time will be small.  Both thread can't use the resource at the same time right?  So one of them has to HALT and wait for the other one to let it in.  That's just how it works.  Calling wait with a smaller number doesn't help and only makes sense if the thread needs to give up or otherwise some other work.

Comment: I've added more details to my answer.

Comment: I've read your edits. You have not understood my question in the least. But I still thank you for trying, though. Also, I am all but an expert on synchronized/wait etc., I only have this *deep* JVM implementation question that I hope someone can answer.

Comment: Take a look at my multithreading score @DreamspacePresident.  I think you are missing some things if you are asking the question.  Best of luck.